# Transform Shape of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I would like to transform a dataframe table like below. It is similar to reverse a one-hot encoding, but not exactly same. Is there an elegant way to do it?

from

[image]

to

[image]

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'17-07-05': {3142: 1.0, 3214: np.nan},
'17-07-12': {3142: 1.0, 3214: np.nan},
'17-07-19': {3142: np.nan, 3214: np.nan},
'website_id': {3142: 3142, 3214: 3214}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`pd.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html)

```
pd.melt(df, 'website_id', var_name='date').sort_values('website_id')

   website_id      date  value
0        3142  17-07-05    1.0
2        3142  17-07-12    1.0
4        3142  17-07-19    NaN
1        3214  17-07-05    NaN
3        3214  17-07-12    NaN
5        3214  17-07-19    NaN
```

Comment: fabulous solution!